# Pull string value from firebase snapshot

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am a new Swift developer.  I'm using Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10.1.

I'm trying to create an array of strings from a firebase snapshot.  I am able to do this by setting up a struct model and using an initializer, but when I want to do it directly in the code without a separate struct it does not work.  Here is my code:

```
    // Get the likers
    dbRef.child("likers").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in

        // Declare an array to hold the Likers
        var retrievedLikers = [String]()

        // Loop through the retrieved likers and put into the array
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let dict = snap.value as! [String:Any]
            let likerId = dict["userId"] as? String ?? ""
            print (likerId)
            retrievedLikers.insert(likerId, at: 0)
        }
            likers = retrievedLikers
        }
```

My firebase data model looks like this:

[image]

I have tried several methods.  The code above is the most recent based on another SO suggestion.

The problem is that I can't create a dictionary with snap.value.  Snap has the correct data.  I am getting an error saying "Could not case value of type '__NSCFString' to 'NSDictionary'.  But the snap is showing as a dictionary.  Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.  I've tried for 3 hours to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let res = snapshot.value as! [String:String] 
retrievedLikers = Array(res.values)
```

---

Here the crash `snap.value` is a `String` that can't be casted to `[String:Any]`

```
let dict = snap.value as! [String:Any]
```